# How to access dynamically created text box in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, datagrid, jakarta-ee

I am trying to create my own grid view. here I retrieve the food items from db and store it into a dynamically created table. these tables has a many row and all the row has a text-box to enter the quantity of the Particular Item. I want this text box to enable only when the check box is checked.

How to do this code.

I used this full day in searching answer for this. I am a beginner of j2ee application. 
Please help me.

Please suggest some sites to find the scripts for accessible and editable data-grid samples.

The codes of that jsp page is as follows:

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %> 
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>  
<html> <head><title>orderSample</title>

    <script language="JavaScript"> <!--

    function enable_text(status,i) { status=!status;  document.orderForm.NAME_TEXT('i').disabled
    = status;///////here is the problem. how to insert i here . i want to do something like this//// } //--> </script>

    </head> 
<body bgcolor="white"> 
<form method=post name=orderForm> 
<h1>Data from the table 'item details' of database 'caffe' in sql </h1> 
<% ResultSet r=null; r=(ResultSet)request.getAttribute("message"); System.out.println(r); int i = 0; %> 
<TABLE cellpadding="15" border="1" style="background-color: #ffffcc;">    <TR>
             <TD>ORDER ID</TD>
            <TD>ORDER PRICE</TD>
            <TD>Quantity</TD>
            <TD>Add Item</TD>
            </TR>
        <%do{

            System.out.println("I am in Ob");
        %>
        <TR>
            <TD><%=r.getString(1)%></TD>
            <TD><%=r.getString(2)%></TD>       
           <!--  <td><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="NAME_TEXT<%=i%>" VALUE="" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=checkBox1, Path=IsChecked}"/></td>-->
            <td><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="NAME_TEXT<%=i%>" VALUE="" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="others<%=i%>" onclick="enable_text(this.checked,<%=i%>)"
    ></td>
        </TR>    <%i++; }while(r.next()); %>
        </TABLE>
        </form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Honestly, this approach is definitely not MVC2. With MVC2 the JDBC code goes in its own Java DAO class, the model goes in its own Javabean class, the HTTP request/response is controlled by a Java Servlet class and the JSP file contains only HTML/JS code, along with taglibs/EL.

Comment: this is the very first application page i am making.. i was in .net before . there we had a dragDrop option for data grid.. 
Can u please suggest me to complete my task in JSP using eclipse

Comment: You're talking about ASP.NET MVC? The Java counterpart is JSF, not JSP with scriptlets and all other concerns mingled.

Comment: k my friend, i give up.i am very sorry for my misunderstanding.
Can u suggest some site links or examples to solve my problem

Comment: If you want to do the same in Java as you did in ASP.NET MVC, then invest time in JSF, not JSP. JSF offers the `<h:dataTable>` as equivalent to ASP.NET MVC's `dataGrid`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable a input text field using a checkbox in the same table row using JavaScript, it's the easiest to grab [jQuery](http://jquery.com).

First, give the checkboxes and input fields in table rows a classname.

```
<td><input type="checkbox" class="add" /></td>
<td><input type="text" class="quantity" /></td>
```

Then, you can use jQuery

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.add').click(function() {
            $(this).closest('tr').find('.quantity').attr('disabled', !this.checked);
        });
    });
</script>
```

This basically tells every checkbox with `class="add"` that when clicked it should lookup the closest parent `<tr>` element and then locate the element with `class="quantity"` and then set its `disabled` attribute with the opposite of the checked state of the checkbox.

Comment: ya this code worked in hiding the text box when it is checked and viseversa .Really thanks a lot.. but how can i access the values in the textBox to pass it into a SQL database..what will be the unique textbox name in each row.

Comment: That's a different question. Press `Ask Question`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285133/how-to-access-dynamically-created-text-box-in-jsp-page